# altering the elements in a list

Tags: python, list, loops, element

I made a list, averaged the numbers in that list, and then tried to subtract the difference and square it, but I get this error "TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment" any one know why? Here's my code:

```
a = [s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6] = eval(input("what's the scores from X1, separate by commas? "))

b = [d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,d9] = eval(input("what's the scores from X2, separate by commas? "))

average1 = (sum (a))/6 
average2 = (sum (b))/9

for j in range (len(a)):
    a[j] = (a[j]-average1)**2

for d in range (len(b)):
    b[d] = (b[d]-average2)**2
```

Comment: Briefly: you're getting an error that tuples don't support item assignment because you're trying to assign to items in a tuple and that isn't supported.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 ` tuples don't support item assignment because you're trying to assign to items in a tuple` A bit circular, no?

Comment: @Alexander - It's simply a clear error message, is all.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I agree, but that quote is pretty recursive :p

Comment: The first eval call creates a tuple which gets unpacked into s1-s6 and also gets bound to the name `a`. Your code doesn't use the s1-s6 names so I don't know why you even have them.  As the linked question mentions, eval is dangerous, especially on unsanitized user input. Instead, get the user input string and split it into a list.

Comment: okay got it, thanks guys.